# Visual Basic - start stopwatch for measuring overtime after a given amount of minutes

Tags: vb.net, encoding, syntax, visual-studio-2017

I'm starting my first steps into Visual Basic and trying to create sort of a stopwatch.

My design is the following:

[image: 1]

The idea behind is to create a tool to support a debate. Persons gets a certain time (7 minutes) for presenting their topic and after that time there is room for interactive conversation (Q&A) set to 13 minutes. The idea is that after 7 minutes a buzzer sounds to stop the presenting time and go over to the interactive part. And after 20 minutes a 2nd stopwatch starts with a buzzer and a red flashing background to indicate that session needs to be terminated.

This is what I already got and I'm pretty shure it can be coded otherwise and maybe easier.
I already got it to the first working stopwatch but I don't get the rest working:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Hundredths As Integer = 0
    Private Seconds As Integer = 0
    Private Minutes As Integer = 0
    Private Hours As Integer = 0
    Private OvertimeHundredths As Integer = 0
    Private OvertimeSeconds As Integer = 0
    Private OvertimeMinutes As Integer = 0
    Private OvertimeHours As Integer = 0

    Private Sub StartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBtn.Click
        If Timer1.Enabled Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            StartBtn.Text = "START"
            Return
        End If

        If Not Timer1.Enabled Then
            Timer1.Start()
            StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
            Return
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Hundredths += 1
        HundredthsTxB.Text = Hundredths.ToString
        SecondsTxB.Text = Seconds.ToString
        MinutesTxB.Text = Minutes.ToString
        HoursTxB.Text = Hours.ToString

        If Hundredths = 10 Then
            Seconds += 1
            Hundredths = 0
        End If

        If Seconds = 60 Then
            Minutes += 1
            Seconds = 0
        End If

        If Minutes = 60 Then
            Hours += 1
            Minutes = 0
        End If

        If Hours = 24 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetBtn.Click
        Hundredths = 0
        Seconds = 0
        Minutes = 0
        Hours = 0
        HundredthsTxB.Text = Hundredths.ToString
        SecondsTxB.Text = Seconds.ToString
        MinutesTxB.Text = Minutes.ToString
        HoursTxB.Text = Hours.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        OvertimeHundredths += 1
        OvertimeHundredthsTxB.Text = OvertimeHundredths.ToString
        OvertimeSecondsTxB.Text = OvertimeSeconds.ToString
        OvertimeMinutesTxB.Text = OvertimeMinutes.ToString
        OvertimeHoursTxB.Text = OvertimeHours.ToString

        If OvertimeHundredths = 10 Then
            OvertimeSeconds += 1
            OvertimeHundredths = 0
        End If

        If OvertimeSeconds = 60 Then
            OvertimeMinutes += 1
            OvertimeSeconds = 0
        End If

        If OvertimeMinutes = 60 Then
            OvertimeHours += 1
            OvertimeMinutes = 0
        End If

        If OvertimeHours = 24 Then
            Timer2.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If Timer1.Interval = 2 Then
            Timer2.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

So any help is welcome. Also I'm keen on learning on how other guru's are thinking and coding.

Comment: The question is too broad. Please make clear what is not working, and what have you tried. Also, consider making several questions, as from what I understand there are several things not working.

Comment: My first concern is to get that second stopwatch (Timer2) triggered after the amount of minutes filled in the textboxes of Presentation (7) and Interaction time (13). This would already be a great way forward for my first version.

Comment: I would suggest only using one timer.  Set its interval to something small, like one second.  Each second, update your form and add one to a counter.  When the counter reaches 420, that means the 7 minutes have passed.  Sound the buzzer to stop the presentation and begin the interactive portion.  When the counter reaches 1200 (13 minutes later, 20 minutes total), sound the second buzzer and begin flashing red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using timers, I would use a `Stopwatch`. This way there is less messing around adding numbers etc. The code below accomplishes what you want apart from sounding a buzzer as I'm presuming you want to implement it your own. It looks worse than it is, but seems to work ok. See code comments for a little explanation

```
Public Class Form1

    Private PresentationTimer As New Stopwatch
    Private InteractiveTimer As New Stopwatch
    Private PresentationMinutes As Integer
    Private InteractiveMinutes As Integer

    'When this timer is enabled, it keeps track of the two stopwatches and checks
    'that they're within the alloted time.
    '
    'When the presentation timer has expired, that one is stopped and the interactive
    'timer is started
    '
    'When the interactive timer has expired, the timer for background flashing starts.
    'To stop the flashing, click the reset button on the form
    Private Sub UiUpdateTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles uiUpdateTimer.Tick
        UpdateUI()
        If PresentationTimer.IsRunning And IsTimeExpired(PresentationTimer, PresentationMinutes) Then
            PresentationTimer.Stop()
            InteractiveTimer.Start()
            'add code here for buzzer to show end of presentation time
        End If
        If InteractiveTimer.IsRunning And IsTimeExpired(InteractiveTimer, InteractiveMinutes) Then
            InteractiveTimer.Stop()
            BackgroundFlashTimer.Enabled = True
            'add code here for buzzer to show end of interactive time
            StartBtn.Text = "START"
        End If

    End Sub

    'checks if the timer passed as a parameter is expired by comparing
    'the number of elapsed minutes with the number of minutes passed in
    'the second parameter
    Private Function IsTimeExpired(tmr As Stopwatch, mins As Integer) As Boolean
        If tmr.Elapsed.Minutes >= mins Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If
    End Function

    'simply updates all the textboxes with the stopwatch values.
    Private Sub UpdateUI()
        HundredthsTxB.Text = Int(PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10).ToString
        SecondsTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString
        MinutesTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString
        HoursTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Hours.ToString
        OvertimeHundredthsTxB.Text = Int(InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10).ToString
        OvertimeSecondsTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString
        OvertimeMinutesTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString
        overtimeHoursTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Hours.ToString
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBtn.Click
        'if either timer is running, stop them both and exit this sub
        If PresentationTimer.IsRunning Or InteractiveTimer.IsRunning Then
            PresentationTimer.Stop()
            InteractiveTimer.Stop()
            StartBtn.Text = "START"
            uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = False
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'if the presentation timer hasn't run yet, check if the minutes values are
        'valid and start it
        If PresentationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds = 0 Then
            PresentationMinutes = CInt(Val(PresentationMinutesTxB.Text))
            InteractiveMinutes = CInt(Val(InteractiveMinutesTxB.Text))
            'if the minutes values are't valid show messagebox and exit this sub
            If PresentationMinutes = 0 Or InteractiveMinutes = 0 Then
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Presentation and Interactive times.")
                Exit Sub
            End If
            'if minutes values are ok start the presentation timer
            uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
            PresentationTimer.Start()
            StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        'if the presentation timer has been running, but is currently stopped,
        'continue the timer and exit this sub
        If Not PresentationTimer.IsRunning And PresentationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0 Then
            uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
            PresentationTimer.Start()
            StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
            Exit Sub
        End If


        'if the interactive timer has been running,but is currently stopped,
        'continue the timer and exit this sub
        If Not InteractiveTimer.IsRunning And InteractiveTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0 Then
            uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
            InteractiveTimer.Start()
            StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
            Exit Sub
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetBtn.Click
        PresentationTimer.Reset()
        InteractiveTimer.Reset()
        uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = False
        StartBtn.Enabled = True
        StartBtn.Text = "START"
        UpdateUI()
        BackgroundFlashTimer.Enabled = False
        Me.BackColor = defaultBackColor
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundFlashTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackgroundFlashTimer.Tick
        StartBtn.Enabled = False
        If Me.BackColor = DefaultBackColor Then
            Me.BackColor = Color.Red
        Else
            Me.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
        End If
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: WOW, I had to read it a few of times to understand a bit your contribution but I start seeing the logic within it.
@DavidWilson To my understanding,  are uiUpdateTimer & BackgroundFlashTimer also Stopwatch attributes and need they also be declared upfront? Because now I receive "uiUpdateTimer/BackgroundFlashTimer is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level."

Comment: Ah yes sorry - you need to add the appropriately named timer controls to your form. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: Thx @DavidWilson. Based on your code I just managed to run the app as wished.

Answer (score 0):

This was my final solution based on David Wilson's contribution:

Public Class Form1

```
Private PresentationTimer As New Stopwatch
Private InteractiveTimer As New Stopwatch
Private ExtraTimeTimer As New Stopwatch
Private PresentationMinutes As Integer
Private InteractiveMinutes As Integer

'When this timer is enabled, it keeps track of the two stopwatches and checks
'that they're within the alloted time.
'
'When the presentation timer has expired, that one is stopped and the interactive
'timer is started
'
'When the interactive timer has expired, the timer for background flashing starts.
'To stop the flashing, click the reset button on the form
Private Sub uiUpdateTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles uiUpdateTimer.Tick
    UpdateUI()
    If PresentationTimer.IsRunning And IsTimeExpired(PresentationTimer, PresentationMinutes) Then
        PresentationTimer.Stop()
        InteractiveTimer.Start()
        Me.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        'add code here for buzzer to show end of presentation time
    End If
    If InteractiveTimer.IsRunning And IsTimeExpired(InteractiveTimer, InteractiveMinutes) Then
        InteractiveTimer.Stop()
        BackgroundFlashTimer.Enabled = True
        ExtraTimeTimer.Start()
        'add code here for buzzer to show end of interactive time
        StartBtn.Text = "START"
    End If

End Sub

'checks if the timer passed as a parameter is expired by comparing
'the number of elapsed minutes with the number of minutes passed in
'the second parameter
Private Function IsTimeExpired(tmr As Stopwatch, mins As Integer) As Boolean
    If tmr.Elapsed.Minutes >= mins Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function

'simply updates all the textboxes with the stopwatch values.
Private Sub UpdateUI()
    HundredthsTxB.Text = Int(PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10).ToString
    SecondsTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString
    MinutesTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString
    HoursTxB.Text = PresentationTimer.Elapsed.Hours.ToString
    OvertimeHundredthsTxB.Text = Int(InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10).ToString
    OvertimeSecondsTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString
    OvertimeMinutesTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString
    OvertimeHoursTxB.Text = InteractiveTimer.Elapsed.Hours.ToString
    ExtraTimeHundredthsTxB.Text = Int(ExtraTimeTimer.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10).ToString
    ExtraTimeSecondsTxB.Text = ExtraTimeTimer.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString
    ExtraTimeMinutesTxB.Text = ExtraTimeTimer.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString
    ExtraTimeHoursTxB.Text = ExtraTimeTimer.Elapsed.Hours.ToString
End Sub

Private Sub StartBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StartBtn.Click
    'if either timer is running, stop them both and exit this sub
    If PresentationTimer.IsRunning Or InteractiveTimer.IsRunning Then
        PresentationTimer.Stop()
        InteractiveTimer.Stop()
        ExtraTimeTimer.Stop()
        StartBtn.Text = "START"
        uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = False
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'if the presentation timer hasn't run yet, check if the minutes values are
    'valid and start it
    If PresentationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds = 0 Then
        PresentationMinutes = CInt(Val(PresTimeTxB.Text))
        InteractiveMinutes = CInt(Val(InterTimeTxB.Text))
        'if the minutes values are't valid show messagebox and exit this sub
        If PresentationMinutes = 0 Or InteractiveMinutes = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter valid Presentation and Interactive times.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        'if minutes values are ok start the presentation timer
        uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
        PresentationTimer.Start()
        StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'if the presentation timer has been running, but is currently stopped,
    'continue the timer and exit this sub
    If Not PresentationTimer.IsRunning And PresentationTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0 Then
        uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
        PresentationTimer.Start()
        StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
        Exit Sub
    End If


    'if the interactive timer has been running,but is currently stopped,
    'continue the timer and exit this sub
    If Not InteractiveTimer.IsRunning And InteractiveTimer.ElapsedMilliseconds > 0 Then
        uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = True
        InteractiveTimer.Start()
        StartBtn.Text = "STOP"
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub ResetBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ResetBtn.Click
    PresentationTimer.Reset()
    InteractiveTimer.Reset()
    ExtraTimeTimer.Reset()
    uiUpdateTimer.Enabled = False
    StartBtn.Enabled = True
    StartBtn.Text = "START"
    UpdateUI()
    BackgroundFlashTimer.Enabled = False
    Me.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundFlashTimer_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackgroundFlashTimer.Tick
    StartBtn.Enabled = False
    If Me.BackColor = DefaultBackColor Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.Red
    Else
        Me.BackColor = DefaultBackColor
    End If
    Me.Update()
End Sub
```